# Category blog from a single user

Tags: com-content

I'm triing to find a way to have a single blog from various users, but that all users can have ther own menuitems with their articles

Is there any way to do it only with com_content?

to filter category blog menuitem by author?

I know I could use subcategories for each, but that would complicate workflow for all and disperse content.

Thanks!

Comment: You may find this Q/A useful: [**List Articles by User**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17110/list-articles-by-author/17112#17112)

Comment: I would consider writing an override for this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this with com_content but a third party extension such as Regular Labs Articles Anywhere can help.

See [filter by article author](https://www.regularlabs.com/forum/articlesanywhere/31947-filter-by-article-author-id#) ID for details.

Comment: Yes, but that's what I'm triing to avoid, wanna keep it as vanilla as possible for future admins...