# Show content from all users for a given Category

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, template-override, layout

I'd like to create a layout that lists the article content from a chosen category.and subcategory for specific users.

I've been looking into overriding the blog layout but I'm not familiar with what the code should look like that spits out for example Subcategory 2 User 1 Article.

Could you point me to the function I should use to do this?

I'm using Joomla 3.6.4.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's that failry straight forward. I guess you need to create a custom model/view for this, although possibly you could override an existing view and do php alchemies on it, to group articles the way you want - yet not sure, as I am not checking the com_content atm. Generally your question is becoming very broad - and looks more like I have this requirement and who would like to do the job. If you could start from somewhere and come back with a certain coding problem, then you could get more help from this site. Otherwise, it would be better to hire someone to do this.

Comment: Fair point. If someone could point me to which function joomla uses to call data from the database, I could research it from there.

Comment: See if answers to this similar question are helpfull http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17110/list-articles-by-author/17112#17112

Comment: It's looking like just programing with PHP to pull the content directly from the database may be the most straight forward. I'm really surprised that saying I want the articles from this category from threse users is not simple with such a powerful CMS.

Comment: So found out that I can pull data from the database using Joomla JDatabase function calls. Looks somewhat straight forward to use. Now for some trial and error as I learn the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

K2 allows you to do that using the `latest` view. I suggest you download K2 and then check the code of the `latest` view there, it should give you an idea on how to create a similar view on the `com_content` extension.

If your website is new and this feature is critical, then you can just use K2 (you can easily migrate your existing content to K2 from within K2). It's an excellent content tool.